# Firebase custom domain redirect www

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting, namecheap

I'm having a problem with a custom domain for a static web that I'm hosting in Firebase. When I go to mydomain.com it works fine but when I go to www.mydomain.com it's not working. Firebase hosting has an option to redirect to mydomain.com if you are trying to go to www.mydomain.com but it seems I haven't been able to verify that I own www.mydomain.com.

I verified mydomain.com using A records but when I try to verify www.mydomain.com it tells me that I should use exactly the same records I used to verify mydomain.com, so I tried to add the same A records twice but it did not work. After that I tried using TXT records to verify www.mydomain.com but it didn't work either. So, what am I doing wrong?? These are the screenshot of Firebase hosting and NameCheap.

[image: Firebase Hosting]

NameCheap

[image: NameCheap Advanced DNS]

the first 2 A records are to verify mydomain.com, the acme-challenge txt record is the one I'm using to trying to verify www.mydomain.com

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directions given by Firebase are wrong. The host value should be `www` and not `www.mydomain.com` when redirecting from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com. It happens the same when trying to verify mydomain.com but instead of `www` it should be `@` like in one of the screenshot of my answer.